# Why wont the color of my (current) nav items be overridden?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small issue with my header section. I am trying (have tried a lot actually) to change the color of the 'current' menu item but with no success. I know I've got to override Bootstrap's default color. However, almost all combinations with the selectors (in my CSS file) so far have failed to do this. What gives?

I have also tried the solutions suggested in similar questions but nothing seems to work.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Collins | Welcome</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pangolin|Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 1.5em;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f4f4f4;
      }

      header {
        background-color: #1B1B1B;
        padding-top: 30px;
        min-height: 70px;
        border-bottom: #228B22 3px solid;
      }

      header a {
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      header li {
        float: left;
        display: inline;
        padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
      }

      header .logo {
        float: left;
      }

      header .logo h1 {
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: -11px;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 25px;
      }

      header .highlight, header #current {
        color: #228B22;
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      header nav {
        float: right;
        margin-top: -8px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
          <h1><span class="highlight">c/o</span> dev-ign</h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li id="current"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

anchors (`a`) need to be targetted specifically

```
header #current a {
  color: #228B22;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```